# Is SHM an example of a jerk?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, harmonic-oscillator, spring, jerk

So i was wondering if simple harmonic motion (SHM) is an example of a jerk (3th derivative of position)?I think it is a jerk because acceleration is changing with respect to time in SHM. Am i correct?

Comment: The only system that has a vanishing 3rd derivative of position would be that of a constant force. I guess most systems have a non vanishing jerk but the equations of motion don't depend on the jerk.

Comment: what is meant by vanishing or non-vanishing?

Comment: Non-vanishing means that it isn't zero.

Comment: SHM is not an example of a jerk. It is a motion *with* a jerk, $\left(\frac{d_3x}{dt^3}\right)$,  *that is non-zero* (except at a couple of times in the cycle). I'm simply making a point about how the term is used in a sentence. We wouldn't, for example, say that SHM is an example of an acceleration, or an example of a velocity...

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration that changes with time in an oscillating system system does meet the definition of a jerk. (A jerk that's noticeable on a daily basis occurs when you are decelerating for a red light and you reach a velocity of zero.)